# Delete or remove last column in CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 5 columns. Using Python, how can I delete the last column (header5 in the example)? Is there an easy way I'm missing, or do I have to loop through all rows in the CSV and remove each value from the last column (which could still leave me with the undesired preceding comma)?

I'm not seeing anything related to this in the CSV module or elsewhere on the interwebs, so any help is much appreciated.

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [csv module](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python2.6/html/library/csv.html#module-csv). When writing out a row, use `row[:-1]` to chop off the last item:

```
import csv

with open(filename,"r") as fin:
    with open(outname,"w") as fout:
        writer=csv.writer(fout)
        for row in csv.reader(fin):
            writer.writerow(row[:-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't use CSV module, the logical and sane way is to read the file row by row, split them on comma, and print out item 1 through 4 with a `join`. eg

```
for line in open("file"):
    print ','.join( line.split(",")[:-1] )
```

Or just by simple string indexing

```
for line in open("file"):
    print line[ : line.rindex(",") ]
```

Comment: This may hit problems if the last column of data happens to contain a comma. Using the CSV module should get around this.