# How do I remove the first part of a line when reading a file?

Tags: python

I found this list of numbers that I have stored in a python document called "test.txt":

```
1 2
2 3
3 2
4 5
5 2
6 3
7 7
8 2
9 11
10 13
11 2
12 3
13 5
14 17
15 19
16 2
17 23
18 7
19 29
20 3
21 31
22 2
23 37
24 41
25 43
26 47
27 5
28 53
29 59
30 2
```

And I am trying to remove the first number of every line and put the second number in a list as an integer so it looks like this:

```
[2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 2, 11, 13, 2, 3, 5, 17, 19, 2, 23, 7, 29, 3, 31, 2, 37, 41, 43, 47, 5, 53, 59, 2]
```

I have tried this bit of code:

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo

frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())

with open("test.py", "rt") as openfile:
   new_list = []
   for line in openfile:
       new_list.append(line.rstrip(str(frameinfo.lineno())))

print(new_list)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileLocation", line 8, in <module>
    new_list.append(line.rstrip(str(frameinfo.lineno())))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: This isn't a valid python document. It's a csv in a misnamed file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete or remove last column in CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245738/delete-or-remove-last-column-in-csv-file-using-python)

Comment: Do you actually have empty lines in your document or is this just from copying the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Biegeleisen's answer should work well.
Another simple approach is to split the line (after striping) using  and taking the second element.

```
with open("test.py", "rt") as openfile:
    new_list = []
    for line in openfile:
        try:
            new_list.append(line.strip().split(' ')[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.sub` here:

```
with open("test.py", "rt") as openfile:
    new_list = []
    for line in openfile:
        new_list.append(re.sub(r'^\d+\s+', '', line))
```

The pattern `^\d+\s+` would match the leading digit (and following whitespace) of any line which began with a line number.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.genfromtxt('test.py')
new_list = x[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
new_list.append(line.rstrip(str(frameinfo.lineno())).split(" ")[1])
```