# Looping through n number of CSV files and deleting columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that I need to add a functionality to, which is to strip out the second column of each Event CSV file which it processes. I've tried the solutions at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/how-to-delete-columns-in-a-csv-file), but I've been unsuccessful in employing any of them.

My CSV files look like this

```
Time/Date,Event #,Event Desc
05/19/2020 20:12:30,29,Advance Drive ON
05/19/2020 20:32:23,29,Advance Drive ON
05/19/2020 20:35:13,29,Advance Drive ON
05/19/2020 20:39:50,37,Discharge 1 Plug Chute Fault
05/19/2020 20:47:40,68,LMI is in OFF Mode
```

And here is my function:

```
# A function to clean the Event Files of raw data
def CleanEventFiles(EF_files, eventHeader, EFmachineID):
    logging.debug(f'Cleaning Event files...')                       # Write to program logger
    for f in EF_files:                                              # FOR ALL FILES IN EVENT FILES
        IsFileReadOnly(f)                                           # check to see if the file is READ ONLY
        print(f'\nCleaning file: {f}')                              # tell user which file is being cleaned
        print('\tReplacing new MachineIDs & File Headers...')       # print stuff to the user
        logging.debug(f'\tReplacing headers for file {f}')          # write to program logger
        with open(f, newline='', encoding='latin-1') as g:          # open file as read
            r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))  # declare read variable while removing NULLs
            next(r)                                                 # remove old machineID
            data = [line for line in r]                             # set list to all data in file
            data[0] = eventHeader                                   # replace first line with new header
            data.insert(0, EFmachineID)                             # add line before header for machine ID
        WriteData(f, data)                                          # write data to the file
```

I know it's got to be something as simple as putting `del r[1]` into a loop somewhere, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out. The best I seem to get is to remove the Event # header on each file, but the data in `data[1]` remains after the file processes.

What would be the best way to go about removing the second column of data from these files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete or remove last column in CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245738/delete-or-remove-last-column-in-csv-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can read all the rows into a list via `csv.DictReader` then that is a fairly straightforward solution. Note, this answer does things one file at a time so you will want to call it for each file.  Note as well that this is currently destructive in that the original file is overwritten.

```py
import csv

def clean_event_file(filename, column_to_remove):

    ##--------------------
    ## read in all the rows at once.
    ## note that this will also get us the headers.
    ##--------------------
    with open(filename, "r") as file_in:
        rows = list(csv.DictReader(file_in))
    headers = [col for col in rows[0].keys() if col != column_to_remove]
    ##--------------------

    ##--------------------
    ## Write out the results again absent the given header
    ##--------------------
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as file_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=headers, extrasaction="ignore")
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)
    ##--------------------

clean_event_file("in.csv", "Event #")
```